# Need border or underline Heading/Section

Tags: graphics, sectioning, titlesec, article, border

I am using the article class and need to underline or put a box around the section. It's a resume heading so it needs to be neat.
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,bottom = 0.6in,left = 0.56in,right = 0.56in,top = 0.6in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage{verbatim}
\newcommand{\xfilll}[2][1ex]{
\dimen0=#2\advance\dimen0 by #1
\leaders\hrule height \dimen0 depth -#1\hfill}
\titleformat{\section}{\large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}
\renewcommand\labelitemi{\raisebox{0.4ex}{\tiny$\bullet$}}
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\cdot$}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{document}
    \section*{\colorbox{lightgray!50}{\hspace{57.5mm}\Large Professional Experience\hspace{57.5mm}}}
\end{document}
```

I tried shifting `/hline` in the upward direction but couldn't do it either.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Is it for a single section?

Comment: It is for all the sections. I have found a solution not very elegant though. ```\section*{\framebox(516,16){\colorbox{lightgray!50}{\hspace{57.5mm}\Large Professional Experience\hspace{57.5mm}}}}```

Comment: This is not a code for a  section \ it will  the vertical spacing around sections.

Comment: Do the headings have to be centred?

Comment: Yes, and It work

Answer (score 0):

I propose this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, bottom=0.6in, left=0.56in, right=0.56in, top=0.6in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage{verbatim}
\newcommand{\xfilll}[2][1ex]{
\dimen0=#2\advance\dimen0 by #1
\leaders\hrule height \dimen0 depth -#1\hfill}
\colorlet{headingcolor}{Gainsboro!50!Lavender!30}
\newcommand{\headingbox}[1]{%
\setlength{\fboxsep}{1ex}\SetTracking[ no ligatures=f]{encoding=*, shape=sc}{70} \colorbox{headingcolor}{\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering#1}}}

\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\filcenter}{}{0em}{\headingbox}
\renewcommand\labelitemi{\raisebox{0.4ex}{\tiny$\bullet$}}
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\cdot$}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}

Some text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text.

\section*{Professional Experience}

Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text…

\end{document}
```

[image]